# How is the secondary turns ratio affected in this POE300F-50L when two coils are in parallell?

Tags: transformer, flyback

I'm planning to use this [POE300F-50L transformer](https://www.coilcraft.com/getmedia/97e91118-2310-45e3-86db-d65a2ae10c8d/poe300.pdf) as illustrated in the picture below. The turns ratio when all pins are connected in parallel is 1:0.14 (Np:Ns). How would connecting them as below change that turns ratio?

The transformer output 5V 6A when all pins are connected in parallel. If it is connected as per method below, would 6A damage the secondary winding?

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a datasheet of this transformer? The turns ratio is not affected, but an overload is possible.

Comment: Hi 
I'm using this one here: 
https://www.coilcraft.com/en-us/products/transformers/power-transformers/power-over-ethernet/poe300/poe300f-50/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *How would connecting them as below change that turns ratio?*

It wouldn't change the turns ratio (assumption: primary windings driven the same in both cases).

> *The transformer output 5V 6A when all pins are connected in parallel.
> If it is connected as per method below, would 6A damage the secondary
> winding?*

Up to 6 amps load current is only available with all three secondaries in parallel. If one secondary is used for something else then, the maximum rated output current would drop proportionately.